# Proof of quotient rule $(\frac{f}{g})'(x_{0})=\frac{f'(x_0)g(x_0)-f(x_0)g'(x_0)}{g^2(x_0)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

$$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'(x_{0})=\frac{f'(x_0)g(x_0)-f(x_0)g'(x_0)}{g^2(x_0)}$$

So, $\frac{1}{g}.f=\frac{f}{g}$, then $$\frac{f}{g}'(x_0)=\frac{f(x)\frac{1}{g(x)}-f(x_0)\frac{1}{g(x_0)}}{x-x_0}=f(x)\frac{\frac{1}{g(x)}-\frac{1}{g(x_0)}}{x-x_0}-\frac{1}{g(x_0)}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ I took the limit of everything as $x \to x_0$ $$=f(x_0)\frac{1}{g'(x_0)}-\frac{1}{g(x_0)}f'(x_0)=\frac{f(x_0)}{g'(x_0)}-\frac{f'(x_0)}{g(x_0)}=\frac{g(x_0)f(x_0)-f'(x_0)g'(x_0)}{g'(x_0)g(x_0)}$$ which clearly it's fake.

Where did I go wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close. Note that instead of cancelling the term $\frac{\frac{f(x)}{g(x_0)}}{x-x_0}$ you actually subtract it twice. Second, note that the $$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{\frac{1}{g(x)} - \frac{1}{g(x_0)}}{x-x_0} = \left(\frac{1}{g(x_0)}\right)'\neq \frac{1}{g'(x_0)}.$$

Instead of doing it this way, I like to prove the quotient rule using the product rule: $\frac{f}{g} = f \cdot g^{-1}$. $\frac{d}{dx} (fg^{-1}) = f'g^{-1} - fg'g^{-2} = \frac{f'g - fg'}{g^2}.$

Comment: Thank you!! I got it right now. I actually think your method is easier haha

Comment: I like doing it like this:  with $f/g = h$, we have $f = gh$; then $f' = g'h + gh'$, or

Comment: I like proving it like this:  with $f/g = h$, we have $f = gh$ whence $f' = g'h + gh'$ and so $h' = (f' - g'h) /  g = (f' - g'(f / g)) / g = ((f'g - g'f)/g) / g = (f'g - g'f) / g^2$.  $OE\Delta$

Answer (score 3):

$(1/g)'\neq 1/g'$ this is where you made the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do it : logarithmic differentiation
$$y=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\implies \log(y)=\log(f(x))-\log(g(x))$$ Differentiate both sides
$$\frac{y'}y=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}-\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(x)\,g(x)-f(x)\,g'(x) } {f(x)\,g(x) }$$
$$y'=y \,\frac{y'}y=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\times \frac{f'(x)\,g(x)-f(x)\,g'(x) } {f(x)\,g(x) }$$ Simplify.